# Using multiple AWS Cognito Userpools for Tenants

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant, amazon-cognito

When building multi-tenant applications in AWS, [SaaS identity and isolation with Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/saas/identity-with-cognito/) uses an individual Cognito Userpool per tenant.

However there is a soft limit for the [maximum number of Userpools available per AWS account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) which is 50 by default. Although it can be increased by contacting the support center, I'm unaware of the Hard Limits.

Does anyone know whether we can increase the limits for 1000s of UserPools or not?

Comment: Amazon sometimes does not publish hard limits. Instead they review requests on a case by case basis. I recommend that you open a support case with AWS Support and include your specific requirements. Based upon my experience they will be happy to help you.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the input, I have already put a limit increase to verify whether it fits to our use case upon putting the question here. The problem here is, its a costly architectural decision and couldn't commit without knowing the limits since ultimately the maximum number of tenants depends on it.

Comment: Ashan, I am curious what the answer will be. Let me know - I work with many customers on Cognito constantly.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have  received approval for limit increase which makes it a possible way to go ahead. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to validate this use-case by requesting a Cognito User Pool limit increase to 500.

This was approved and it seems that its a possible way to go ahead having multiple Cognito Userpools for each tenant for multi-tenant applications. This improves the ability for.

- Enforcing tenant isolation, through IAM policies and Roles
- Preserve tenant context propagated through the request pipeline from Login to Data access.
- Allows to have custom policies for each tenant (e.g Password length, MFA & etc.)

Note: This can also add additional complexity for small size, multi-tenancy requirements and generally preferred for medium, large and enterprise projects with compliance and isolation requirements.

Comment: Ashan, Thank you for the update. Good information to know for my customers.